# How can I fix 'Unhandled Promise Rejection' for my Vue application?

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, error-handling, es6-promise

For my Vue application I encounter the following issue in IE: **'Unhandled Promise Rejection undefined'**.

I tracked the issue down to the authentication of the application. But I'm not sure how to tackle it. I've tried try-catch blocks around the next() functions.

Below the code of the authentication.

```
import router from '@/config/Router';
import CONST from '@/utils/Constants';
import ObjectHelper from "@/helpers/ObjectHelper";

class Auth {
    constructor() {
      router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
          if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {

            if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
              next({path: CONST.ROUTE.SESSION.LOGIN});
            } else {
              next();
            }
          } else {
              next();
          }
      });
    }

    static logOut() {
      localStorage.clear();
      sessionStorage.clear();

      router.replace(CONST.ROUTE.SESSION.LOGIN);
    }

    static isLoggedIn() {
      return ObjectHelper.exists(localStorage.getItem(CONST.KEY.AUTH.ACCESS_TOKEN));
    }
}

export default Auth;
```

After `this.$router.push(CONST.ROUTE.ORGANISATIONS.OVERVIEW);` in my login-component, the error is thrown.

To be complete, I also provide the code for the Router:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: () => import('@/views/home/home.vue')
    },{
      path: '/session',
      name: 'session',
      component: () => import('@/views/session/session.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: 'login',
          name: 'login',
          component: () => import('@/views/session/login/login.vue')
        },
        {
          path: 'logout',
          name: 'logout',
          component: () => import('@/views/session/logout/logout.vue')
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/organisations',
      alias: '/organisaties',
      component: () => import('@/views/organisations/organisations.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'organisations-overview',
          component: () => import('@/views/organisations/overview/overview.vue'),
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            can: 'edit-organisations',
            fail: '/session/logout'
          }
        },
        {
          path: ':uuid',
          name: 'organisation-edit',
          component: () => import('@/views/organisations/edit/edit.vue'),
          meta: {
            requiresAuth: true,
            can: 'edit-organisations',
            fail: '/session/logout'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Anyone an idea how to tackle this? Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is the problem the unhandled promise rejection or the underlying error? If you expect code to throw, wrap it in a `try`-`catch` block and log the error.

Comment: If possible try to post some more details about the issue. With only the above code, we are not able to find the cause for the issue. Does it show any other error or warning?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the feedback. There are no other errors thrown. I only see the 'Unhandled promise rejection undefined' in the browsers console. I've edited the code in the description, so it gives more info about the code.

Comment: Did you try to put the Try catch around the IF ELSE condition to see whether it gives an idea about the issue?

Comment: I found the issue(s).  I needed to add support for IE11 to my Vue project: ```'babel-polyfill', 'weakmap-polyfill', 'core-js/es/set', 'core-js/es/map'```. After this, everything works fine. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for 'Unhandled Promise Rejection undefined' in IE. I needed to add support for IE11 to my Vue project: 'babel-polyfill', 'weakmap-polyfill', 'core-js/es/set', 'core-js/es/map'. After this, everything works fine.